# fetch dropdownlist selected value in NeedDatasource event of radgrid in asp.net ajax web application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik-grid

I want to fetch value from dropdownlist when selected. On that selection of value I am firing a simple select query ie.

"select * from Category where cat_name ='" + dropdownlistselectedvalue + "'"

here is the code of needDatasource

protected void rdgridview_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsFromDetailTable)
        {
                //I want to fetch the dropdownlist selected value here ie

```
          string dpvalue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

      string strqry = "select * from Categories where Category_Name = '"+ dpvalue +"'";

        rdgridview.DataSource = getDataTable(strqry);            
    }
}
```

But I am not able to fetch the value from the dropdownlist selected value in needDatasource method. How shall I fetch the value or fire any event of dropdownlist control?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a detailed documentation. You might want to try simple data binding. Check it [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/simplebinding/defaultcs.aspx). 
For NeedsDataSource documentation, check [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.radgrid-needdatasource_ev.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily by saving the dropdownlist selected value in a `ViewState`, do that in the  `SelectedIndexChanged`  event for the dropdownlist .

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["List1_Value"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

}
```

then get the value from `ViewState` in the `needDatasource` event:

```
string strqry = "select * from Categories where Category_Name = '" + ViewState["List1_Value"]+ "'";
```